# Is it possible to generate a Shopify customerAccessToken without the user entering their email and password?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to create a website and mobile app that seamlessly uses Shopify for purchases. The users will log into my site to create an account with an email and password. I would like to associate purchases with these accounts.

I can let a user enter a username and password an generate a customerAccessToken but I don't want them to have to do that and the password would be different from their website password.

I'm aware that Shopify has a Multipass system which redirects users through Shopify to associate the two accounts. However this is a Shopify Plus only option which is prohibitively expensive and I also don't think (though I might be wrong on this) that this would work in a mobile app situation.

Is there any other way to authenticate a user on the Storefront API?

Answer (score 1):

You can not generate it without entering them.
Check this mutation.

```
mutation customerAccessTokenCreate($input: CustomerAccessTokenCreateInput!) {
  customerAccessTokenCreate(input: $input) {
    customerAccessToken {
      accessToken
      expiresAt
    }
    customerUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}

{
  "input": {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "password": "HiZqFuDvDdQ7"
  }
}
```